# I'm getting a Memory Error while processing my dataset in python ? What could be the reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, deep-learning, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying a deep learning code for processing my dataset which consists 1,12,120 images. What my code does is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import imageio
from os import listdir
import skimage.transform
import pickle
import sys, os
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

def get_labels(pic_id):
    labels = meta_data.loc[meta_data["Image Index"]==pic_id,"Finding Labels"]
    return labels.tolist()[0].split("|")
#Loading Data
meta_data = pd.read_csv(data_entry_path)
bbox_list = pd.read_csv(bbox_list_path)
with open(train_txt_path, "r") as f:
train_list = [ i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
with open(valid_txt_path, "r") as f:
    valid_list = [ i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
    label_eight = list(np.unique(bbox_list["Finding Label"])) + ["No Finding"]

# transform training images
print("training example:",len(train_list))
print("take care of your RAM here !!!")
train_X = []
for i in range(len(train_list)):
    image_path = os.path.join(image_folder_path,train_list[i])
    img = imageio.imread(image_path)
    if img.shape != (1024,1024): # there some image with shape (1024,1024,4) in training set
        img = img[:,:,0]
        img_resized = skimage.transform.resize(img,(256,256)) # or use img[::4] here
        train_X.append((np.array(img_resized)/255).reshape(256,256,1))
        if i % 3000==0:
            print(i)
train_X = np.array(train_X)
np.save(os.path.join(data_path,"train_X_small.npy"), train_X)

# transform validation images
print("validation example:",len(valid_list))
valid_X = []
for i in range(len(valid_list)):
    image_path = os.path.join(image_folder_path,valid_list[i])
    img = imageio.imread(image_path)
    if img.shape != (1024,1024):
        img = img[:,:,0]
        img_resized = skimage.transform.resize(img,(256,256))
#     if img.shape != (1024,1024):
#             train_X.append(img[:,:,0])
#     else:
    valid_X.append((np.array(img_resized)/255).reshape(256,256,1))
    if i % 3000==0:
        print(i)

valid_X = np.array(valid_X)
np.save(os.path.join(data_path,"valid_X_small.npy"), valid_X)


# process label
print("label preprocessing")

train_y = []
for train_id in train_list:
    train_y.append(get_labels(train_id))
valid_y = []
for valid_id in valid_list:
    valid_y.append(get_labels(valid_id))


encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer()
encoder.fit(train_y+valid_y)
train_y_onehot = encoder.transform(train_y)
valid_y_onehot = encoder.transform(valid_y)
train_y_onehot = np.delete(train_y_onehot, [2,3,5,6,7,10,12],1) # delete out 8 and "No Finding" column
valid_y_onehot = np.delete(valid_y_onehot, [2,3,5,6,7,10,12],1) # delete out 8 and "No Finding" column

with open(data_path + "/train_y_onehot.pkl","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(train_y_onehot, f)
with open(data_path + "/valid_y_onehot.pkl","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(valid_y_onehot, f)
with open(data_path + "/label_encoder.pkl","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(encoder, f)
```

So this is my code My system configration:Intel i7-7700HQ,16GB Ram,256GB ssd,GTX 1050 4GB

Is there a way to split my dataset so and write to the same file again? I'm also posting the error which i got as a screenshot [Error From Powershell after executing the code for 30mins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmvdv.png)

I'm also using python3 in my system 64bit version

**Does spliting the 1,12,120 images and taking them as batches will it work here? If yes how?**

Comment: A back of the envelope calculation says 78,000 * 256 * 256 * 3 = 15.5gb, so it seems that you're running out of memory right on schedule. There are options for dealing with this but they depend on what your overall goal is.

Comment: Is there anyway to overcome this ?

Comment: Fix your formatting, and post a smaller proof of concept. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is the best I can do sir this is the same way how I wrote the code

Comment: The trivial answer is to downsample your images more or to use fewer images. You could preprocess all your data, save it to a new file and memory map that file (but it would almost certainly work terribly). The real answer is that this is approaching an HPC scale problem.

Comment: Is there any way to split the dataset and train the file can anyone explain it using this program

Comment: I'm tempted to say that you don't use `train_X` after saving it, so you might not get the error if you do `del(train_X)` after the save. However, you're likely going to use it later on, won't you?

Comment: Yes I need the train_X for later for the next stage after this

Comment: something to try:  dereference train_X after you save it (train_X = None), same with valid_X.  Then after all is done (but before you "need them again"), open them up in memmapped mode: X_train = np.load("train_X_small.npy", mmap_mode='r')  but this will mean you need many more Gigs of disk space...an ssd drive would be preferred.  the better solution would be to use "generators" but that would mean you changing your code which you don't want to do.

Comment: Could you please show me by pasting the code here from above